# Can you help me with understanding the terms of the INNER JOIN ON

Tags: sql, inner-join

SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;

Here is the template I found online for INNER JOIN ON.

Here is what I have understand so far.

There are two tables with data. We need data from both.

SELECT is used to display 
FROM is from what table do we wish to SELECT(display)
INNER JOIN creates a new result table by combining column values of table 1 and 2

This is as far as I've understood. I'm struggling with 
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;

Especially the word "ON" is really not making any sense to me.

If someone could kindly explain this to me I'd be most thankfull

Comment: [This](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is a good explanation

Comment: INNER JOIN is a intersection between 2 tables. In order for the intersection to be done we need a common column between these tables. ON clause specifies which is the common column for each on those tables

Comment: INNER JOIN - matches results from both tables where (ON) common_field in table1 is equal to common_field in table2

Comment: Logically `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2`  gives a `CROSS JOIN` with every permutation of rows form both tables. The predicate in the `ON` clause then determines which rows to keep from that.

If you use `1=1` as the join predicate this is always true so you just get the `CROSS JOIN`. `table1.common_field = table2.common_field` will just preserve the rows where that condition is met. 

Physically this is likely to be implemented much more efficiently than generating the cross join and preserving the rows to keep but the logical description is still true.

Comment: @JohnHC: no it's not. Those dreaded Venn diagrams completely miss the point that a JOIN between two tables in a one-to-many relationship will duplicate information from the "one" entity - which is something that most newcomers find very surprising.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name given the OP's demonstrated level of knowledge, it's a good starting point to understand the base concepts. Of course there is more to it, but that can come later.

Comment: Thank you all who responded.

Comment: Does it matter which side the common columns come after the ON predicate e.g. SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Employee_Data INNER JOIN Department ON Department.EmployeeID = Employee_Data.EmployeeID. Would it matter if we said ...ON Employee_Data.EmployeeID = Department.EmployeeID

Comment: If you understand my comment above you should know the answer is "no". There are no circumstances where `Department.EmployeeID = Employee_Data.EmployeeID` is true but `Employee_Data.EmployeeID = Department.EmployeeID` isn't. It is like saying that `1 + 3 == 4` but `4 != 1 + 3`